# Вызвать фрагмент кода в функции JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Есть код в листинге 1 и есть функция в листинге 2. Оба фрагмента находятся в одном файле и фрагмент из листинга 1 хорошо отрабатывает в других функциях, как только доходит до функции из листинга 2, перестает работать. Если скопировать целиком фрагмент в функцию, то все работает, но хочется как-то проще сделать. Как можно вызвать в функции часть кода?

listing 1

```js
var get_number = obj.Price.Itog;
var get_сurrency = obj.Currency.symbol;

function declOfNum(get_number, titles) {
  return titles[(get_number % 10 == 1 && get_number % 100 != 11) ? 0 : get_number % 10 >= 2 && get_number % 10 <= 4 && (get_number % 100 < 10 || get_number % 100 >= 20) ? 1 : 2]; //v3 
}
if (get_сurrency == 'грн') {
  var final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['грИвна', 'грИвны', 'грИвен']);
} else if (get_сurrency == 'сом') {
  var final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['сом', 'сома', 'сомов']);
} else if (get_сurrency == 'тг') {
  var final_currency = 'тенгЕ';
} else {
  var final_currency = declOfNum(get_number, ['рУбль', 'рублЯ', 'рублЕй']);
}
```

listing 2

```js
function GenTextPriceHour(obj) {
  var t = '';
  var coeff;

  if (obj.Tariff.tunes.C_PRICE_FACTOR == null) {
    coeff = 1;
  } else {
    coeff = obj.Tariff.tunes.C_PRICE_FACTOR;
  }

  if (obj) {
    if (obj.Price.Discount) {
      t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceWithDiscountHour', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), final_currency]) + ' ';
    } else {
      t = t + getText(obj.Language.code, 'PriceNoDiscountHour', [Round(obj.Price.Itog), final_currency]) + ' ';
    }
  }
  return t;
}
```

Comment: "перестает работать" - говорит: "Не буду работать!"?

Comment: Чтобы вызвать часть кода нужно вынести его в ещё одну функцию

Comment: @Igor просто ни чего не возвращается. Должна возвращаться цена и валюта которая была прогнана через кусок кода из 1 листинга.

Comment: @Nick прикольно, но в других функциях этот кусок кода работает почему-то (магия), тогда придется его вызывать еще в других местах.